# Problems with distributed ray tracing and particle system

Tags: raytracing, rendering, 3d, directx12, particles

based on the ray tracing stunning effect, I'm considering a resilient distributed ray tracing implementation, I've just finished a basic computer graphics course, and I'm currently working on directX and directML, I'd like to ask if the particle system and rendering in computer graphics can be scheduled based on directX with a distributed program  such as MPI to schedule multiple GPUs to work on it?